# How to get item from local storage?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a todo list app with react.

I'm trying to adding todos to local storage but I'm stuck in the getItem part. I don't know where to put.

Right now, showing in local storage section but when I refresh the page it is not showing in todolist section.

```
function App() {

 const [change, setChange] = useState();

 const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   console.log(todos);

 });

 const ChangeValue = (e) => {
   setChange(e.target.value);
 };

 const AddTodo = (e) => {

   const TodoId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1

   const newTodo = { content: change, id: TodoId }

   localStorage.setItem('todoInLocalStorage',change);


   setTodos((oldTodos) => [...oldTodos, newTodo]);

   e.preventDefault()
 };

 const DeleteButton = (id) => {
   setTodos(todos.filter((item)=> item.id !== id));
 };

 const DeleteAll = () => {
   setTodos([]);
 };

 return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="frame">
       <h1>To Do List</h1>
       <FormInput ChangeValue={ChangeValue} AddTodo={AddTodo}/>
       <div className="card-2">
         <h2><u>To Do's</u></h2>
         <div className="todos">
            <Todos todos={todos} DeleteButton={DeleteButton}/>
         </div>
       </div>
       <button onClick={DeleteAll} className="ClearTodo">
         Clear All To Do
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see a `getItem` call anywhere.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to save the entire list of todos in the storage or just the last one's text?

Comment: I tried but didn't add it here

Comment: @RonB. After solving the last one, I thought I would add the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this:

Every time your `todos` changes, have a `useEffect` that saves it to the `localStorage`. As for initialization, just use it as the initial value of `useState` for `todos`

There are three things you need to do:

1. Add

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
   }, [todos])
   ```
2. Remove any other `localStorage.setItem` call outside of this `useEffect` (because the `todos` state will be automatically saved to `localStorage` every time it changes)
3. Initialize your `todos` state like so:

   ```
   const [todos, setTodos] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []);
   ```

   That way, the initial value will be either what you saved, or if it doesn't exist will default to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely add it while initializing the todo in the `useState` call like this:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(localStorage.getItem('todoInLocalStorage') ? localStorage.getItem('todoInLocalStorage') : []);
```

In the above code we are first checking if there's any todo present in localstorage, If not we are assigning the default value as empty array.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) but I get a "todos.map is not a function" error. In the todos.js file I map the todos item.

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {

 const [change, setChange] = useState();

const [todos, setTodos] = useState(localStorage.todoInLocalStorage ?localStorage.todoInLocalStorage : [] );

 useEffect(() => {
   console.log(todos);

 });

 const ChangeValue = (e) => {
   setChange(e.target.value);
 };

 const AddTodo = (e) => {

   const TodoId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1

   const newTodo = { content: change, id: TodoId }

   localStorage.setItem('todoInLocalStorage',change);


   setTodos((oldTodos) => [...oldTodos, newTodo]);

   e.preventDefault()
 };

 const DeleteButton = (id) => {
   setTodos(todos.filter((item)=> item.id !== id));
   localStorage.todoInLocalStorage(todos.filter((item)=> item.id !== id));
 };

 const DeleteAll = () => {
   setTodos([]);
   localStorage.removeItem('todoInLocalStorage')
 };

 return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="frame">
       <h1>To Do List</h1>
       <FormInput ChangeValue={ChangeValue} AddTodo={AddTodo}/>
       <div className="card-2">
         <h2><u>To Do's</u></h2>
         <div className="todos">
            <Todos todos={todos} DeleteButton={DeleteButton}/>
         </div>
       </div>
       <button onClick={DeleteAll} className="ClearTodo">
         Clear All To Do
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I get same "todos.map is not a function" error.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))

Answer (score -1):

```
localStorage.getItem('keyWhichYouSetInLocalStorage')
```